# How to use multiple login pages one for admin and the other one for user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want two different login pages. One for admins and the other one for users.

Using the code below only the class with `@Order(1)` works when I remove the `@Order` annotation from the static classes, only the last one works. I used them in two different `ConfigSecurity` files, and it didn't work.

I m expecting for both of them to work. Yet only one is working.

```java
package com.example.FlightAgency.security;
import com.example.FlightAgency.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class App1ConfigurationAdapter {
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new UserService();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/user/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/user/login")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class App2ConfigurationAdapter {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            return http.build();
        }
    }
}    `
```

Answer (score 12):

Both security filter chains are not restricted (default is `/**`).

**Spring Security 6**

You have to restrict the first one with [`securityMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.0/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#securityMatcher(java.lang.String...)), see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0.0/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances):

> **Multiple HttpSecurity Instances**
>
> We can configure multiple `HttpSecurity` instances just as we can have multiple `<http>` blocks in XML. The key is to register multiple `SecurityFilterChain` `@Beans`. The following example has a different configuration for URL’s that start with `/api/`.
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
>   @Bean                                                             
>   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
>       // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
>       UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
>       InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
>       manager.createUser(users.username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
>       manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
>       return manager;
>   }
>
>   @Bean
>   @Order(1)                                                        
>   public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>           .securityMatcher("/api/**")                                   
>           .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
>               .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
>           )
>           .httpBasic(withDefaults());
>       return http.build();
>   }
>
>   @Bean                                                            
>   public SecurityFilterChain formLoginFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>           .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
>               .anyRequest().authenticated()
>           )
>           .formLogin(withDefaults());
>       return http.build();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 1. Configure Authentication as usual.
> 2. Create an instance of `SecurityFilterChain` that contains `@Order` to specify which `SecurityFilterChain` should be considered first.
> 3. The `http.securityMatcher` states that this `HttpSecurity` is applicable only to URLs that start with `/api/`.
> 4. Create another instance of `SecurityFilterChain`. If the URL does not start with `/api/`, this configuration is used. This configuration is considered after `apiFilterChain`, since it has an `@Order` value after `1` (no `@Order` defaults to last).

Comment: What if a matcher like “api” can work on the first layer authentication and also on an oauth2 authentication on a resource server? How do I configure it?

Comment: @jetpack Only the first matching filter chain is applied, all others are skipped. But you can always use different authentications in one filter chain. The user could then choose one to authenticate.

Comment: thank you! This is helpful. Also on old versions, it is the requestmatchers that matches whichh filter to call. Of course, it would follow  the filters order sequence. What I mean about the “/api” matchers are antmatchers. Sorry for the confusing terms I use but this thread help me in the right direction.

Comment: alternative way - instead of providing custom UserDetailsService, can provide custom AuthenticationManager based on the default one provided by Spring Security. this also works with Spring Boot 2.7.X (use requestMatchers instead of securityMatcher). see https://www.devxperiences.com/pzwp1/2023/01/31/spring-boot-security-configuration-practically-explained-part6-a-deep-intro-to-filter-token-based-security/