# Can not use two security configs in my Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have `MasterSecurity` config which is to manage login of masters. And
`AdminSecurity` config which manages admin login.

When I comment one out the other works. But when I try to use both then the master login shows

> PostMapping not allowed

```java
package Spring.LoginRegister.Config;

import Spring.LoginRegister.Entity.RolesConstant;
import Spring.LoginRegister.Repository.AdminRepository;
import Spring.LoginRegister.Service.CustomAdminDetailsService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class AdminSecurityConfig  {

    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService1(){
        return new CustomAdminDetailsService(adminRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder1(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider1(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider= new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService1());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder1());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain AdminsecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider1());
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((request) -> request
                .requestMatchers("/AdminDashBoard/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/login").hasRole(RolesConstant.ROLE_ADMIN.toString() )
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin((form) ->form
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/AdminDashBoard", true)                
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(form -> form
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My problem is they both work individually when one is removed from the app. When I try to combine both only the admin config works properly. This error comes

```
Method 'POST' is not supported.
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:441)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:382)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:504)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
```

This is my second config:

```java
package Spring.LoginRegister.Config;

import Spring.LoginRegister.Repository.MasterRepository;
import Spring.LoginRegister.Service.CustomAdminDetailsService;
import Spring.LoginRegister.Service.CustomMasterDetails;
import Spring.LoginRegister.Service.CustomMasterDetailsService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class MASTERSecurityConfig  {
    private MasterRepository masterRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService2(){
        return new CustomMasterDetailsService(masterRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder2(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider2(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider2= new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider2.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService2());
        authProvider2.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder2());
        return authProvider2;
    }

    @Bean

    public SecurityFilterChain MastersecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider2());
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((request) ->request
                .requestMatchers("/master/home/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/master/login")
                .hasRole(RolesConstant.ROLE_HOUSEMASTER.toString())
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin((form) ->form
                .loginPage("/master/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/master/home", true)
                .permitAll())
            .logout(form -> form
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
            );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I tried  StackOverflow previous answers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user

Answer (score 0):

Do not make separate Config classes. Just make multiple security filter chains and order them accordingly. Also, you have to prevent creating Beans of relative components as beans are global and they will contradict with each other.

Comment: why @Giddy is google broken?

Comment: Can’t find any result for Security 6