# Migrating to Spring Security 6 along with Swagger configuration and custom filters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

I am trying to migrate Spring Boot application from 2.x to 3.x.

On Spring Boot 2.x, I have two configurations extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, one for privately providing API documentations via Swagger, and the other for regular API requests.

Below are two pre-existing, well working Spring Security configuration files.

By *well-working* , I implemented three requirements below.

- Users must provide username, password to access Swagger at `/swagger-ui/index.html`
- `v1/auth/login` should not be handled with `JWTRequestFilter`, since users do not have any JWTs before logging-in.
- Any other endpoints should be protected via `JWTRequestFilter`.

```kotlin
// Configuration file for Swagger
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
class SwaggerConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
   
   // ommitted..

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole(SWAGGER_USER_ROLE)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("passwordEncoder")
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder): UserDetailsService {
        val user = User.builder()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()::encode)
            .username(SWAGGER_USERNAME)
            .password(SWAGGER_PASSWORD)
            .roles(SWAGGER_USER_ROLE)
            .build()
        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user)
    }
}

// Configuration file for regular API calls.
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig(
    private val jwtVerifier: JwtVerifier,
    private val authenticationEntryPoint: AuthenticationEntryPoint
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http {
            httpBasic {
                disable()
            }
            headers {
                frameOptions { disable() }
            }
            csrf { disable() }
            cors { configurationSource = corsConfigurationSource() }
            logout { disable() }
            sessionManagement {
                sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
            }
            addFilterBefore(
                JWTRequestFilter(jwtVerifier, authenticationEntryPoint),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
            addFilterAfter(
                RequestLoggingFilter(),
                JWTRequestFilter::class.java
            )
            exceptionHandling {
                authenticationEntryPoint
            }
        }
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        web.ignoring()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/auth/login")
    }
}
```

As I try to migrate to Spring Boot 3.0.5, which uses Spring Security 6, I have followed [official Spring Security](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) docs to change my code, as WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated.

Below is my changed code.

```kotlin
// In SwaggerConfig
@Bean(value = ["swaggerConfigFilterChain"])
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
        .hasRole(SWAGGER_USER_ROLE)
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
    return http.build()
}

// In SecurityConfig
@Bean(value = ["securityConfigFilterChain"])
@Order(2)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .httpBasic{ it.disable() }
        .headers { header -> header.frameOptions { it.disable() } }
        .csrf { it.disable() }
        .cors { it.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()) }
        .logout { it.disable() }
        .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
        .addFilterBefore(JWTRequestFilter(jwtVerifier, authenticationEntryPoint), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .addFilterAfter(RequestLoggingFilter(), JWTRequestFilter::class.java)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    return http.build()
}

@Bean(value = ["securityConfigWebSecurityCustomizer"])
fun webSecurityCustomizer(): WebSecurityCustomizer {
    return WebSecurityCustomizer { web: WebSecurity ->
        web.ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/auth/login")
    }
}
```

After migrating to the code above, Swagger still required username, password authentication, which is what I wanted, and `v1/auth/login` is not being processed via `JWTRequestFilter`, which is also what I wanted.

However, every other paths are **not being handled with `JWTRequestFilter`**. The filter itself is not being invoked, and the only response I get is 401(UNAUTHORIZED), with an empty response body.

What am I missing?

- If I change the `@Order` between `SwaggerConfig` and `SecurityConfig`, `JWTRequestFilter` is being invoked correctly, but it is also invoked on Swagger endpoints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple login pages one for admin and the other one for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I should have used `securityMatcher()`.

In Spring Security, we are able to configure which `SecurityFilterChain` should be called by API path patterns.

[image: Spring Security SecurityFilterChain Achitecture]

The problem with my previous code was that I was using `requestMatchers()` inside `authorizeHttpRequests()`, whilst I should have been using `securityMatcher()` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-security-matchers) to define which `SecurityFilterChain` should be called when specific API path pattern is called.

Below is my updated code. It works regardless of `@Order` annotation.

```kotlin
// In SwaggerConfig class.
@Bean(value = ["swaggerConfigFilterChain"])
@Order(2)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .securityMatcher("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.requestMatchers(
                AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**", HttpMethod.GET.name()),
                AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
                .hasRole(SWAGGER_USER_ROLE)
                .and().httpBasic()
        }
    return http.build()
}

// In SecurityConfig class.
@Bean(value = ["securityConfigFilterChain"])
@Order(1)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity):  DefaultSecurityFilterChain{
    http
        .httpBasic{ it.disable() }
        .headers { header -> header.frameOptions { it.disable() } }
        .csrf { it.disable() }
        .cors { it.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()) }
        .logout { it.disable() }
        .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
        .securityMatcher("/v1/**", "/v2/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.requestMatchers("/v1/**", "/v2/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(JWTRequestSecurityConfig(jwtVerifier, authenticationEntryPoint))
                .and()            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        }
    return http.build()
}
```

If you set debug to true in `@EnableWebSecurity`, like `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)`, you can see which filters are called to process a request.

Before applying `securityMatcher()`, the filters(filter chain) called were `@Bean` with lower `@Order` configured regardless of API path pattern.

However, after applying `securityMatcher()`, filters called to process were different by path patterns I have defined.

For example, when I call Swagger (`GET /swagger-ui/index.html`), below filters are called.

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

But when I call for example, `POST /v2/some-api`, which satisfies the pattern `.securityMatcher("/v1/**", "/v2/**")`, below filters are called.

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  JWTRequestFilter
  RequestLoggingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```