# How to run filters on specific paths in Spring Boot 3.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to use a filter with different parameters on specific endpoints. For example I have `/api/users/**` and I want to apply a filter that verifies the JWT token to have `USER` or `ADMIN` permission, same for `/api/admins/**`.

In Spring Boot 3.1.0 I didn't find how to do this exactly, but I tried to update the old solutions. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work, it runs both filters instances for /api/admins/get and /api/users/get .

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    public final JwtService jwtService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable();
                })
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.disable();

                })
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer
                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                });
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(jwtService, List.of("USER", "ADMIN")), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/admins/**").permitAll();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(jwtService, List.of("ADMIN")), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final List<String> roles;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

        roles.forEach(System.out::println);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the reason for you not reading the chapter called ”jwt” in the spring security documentation?

Comment: I think it's easier this way, but I also might be wrong. I did not find something regarding JWT in the Spring Security documentation, only OAuth JWT.

Comment: Eh you need to read up what ”oath jwt” actually is. Because you are completly wrong. It is not used for only google and facebook. You have built something that already exists in spring security.

Comment: *but I tried to update the old solutions* As far as I see, your old solution never worked. So your updated old solution can't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple login pages one for admin and the other one for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user)

Comment: You need two security filter chains to seperate different authentication paths.

Comment: The solution of @Bernard Menezes works. I will also take a look of "oath jwt" to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in Spring Security documentation, you can register multiple **SecurityFilterChain**, each one related to an path pattern. After that, the **FilterChainProxy** will decide which **SecurityFilterChain** to invoke. The following picture illustrate this flow. More details in [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-securityfilterchain).

[image: FilterChainProxy diagram flow]

It should work if you change your SecurityConfig to:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    public final JwtService jwtService;

    private void sharedSecurityConfiguration(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer
                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainUsersAPI(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        sharedSecurityConfiguration(httpSecurity);
        httpSecurity
                .securityMatcher("/api/users/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(jwtService, List.of("USER", "ADMIN")), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainAdminsAPI(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        sharedSecurityConfiguration(httpSecurity);
        httpSecurity
                .securityMatcher("/api/admins/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(jwtService, List.of("ADMIN")), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}
```