# Second SecurityFilterChain bean is ignored, and first one in order is applied to all APIs instead

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created two FilterSecurityChain beans to handle authorization for different entrypoints of my Spring Boot app.

Specifically, all APIs of my app accept a JWT as the only authorization method, but `api1` and `api2` accept JWTs issued only by `issuer-1`, and `api3` and `api4` accept JWTs issued only by `issuer-2`.

What happens:

- when I call `api1` with a JWT issued by `issuer-1`, the authorization passes -> OK
- when I call `api1` with a JWT issued by `issuer-2`, the app responds with 401 -> OK
- when I call `api3` with a JWT issued by `issuer-1`, the authorization passes -> NOT OK
- when I call `api3` with a JWT issued by `issuer-2`, the app responds with 401 -> NOT OK

It seems like that the security chain filter of `api1` and `api2` are applied also to `api3` and `api4` which is not what I want.

If, for sake of example, I switch the `Order` of the filters, then I get the opposite result.(`api1` and `api2` are authorized with a JWT valid only for `api3` and `api4`).

Please, see the code below.

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    fun securityFilterChainExternalEndpoints(http: HttpSecurity, appProperties: AppProperties): SecurityFilterChain? {
        val customAuthenticationManagerResolver = JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(
            "issuer-1"
        )

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/api1/**",
                "/api/api2/**"
            )
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer {
                it.authenticationManagerResolver(customAuthenticationManagerResolver)
            }

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun securityFilterChainInternalEndpoints(http: HttpSecurity, appProperties: AppProperties): SecurityFilterChain? {
        val customAuthenticationManagerResolver = JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(
            "issuer-2"
        )

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/api/api3/**",
                "/api/api4/**"
            )
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer {
                it.authenticationManagerResolver(customAuthenticationManagerResolver)
            }

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple login pages one for admin and the other one for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `securityMatcher` in the filter-chain with lower `@Order` => it intercepts all requests and the one(s) with higher `@Order` never gets a chance to be tried.