# Spring Security 6 multiple login mechanisms

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-6

Prior to updating from Spring Security 5.3.24 I was able to dynamically configure multiple login solutions on an HttpSecurity such as saml2Login, and two formLogin with differing loginProcessingUrl configurations e.g.

```
(httpSecurity
                                       .authorizeRequests()
                                   .antMatchers("/index.html","/static/**").permitAll()
                                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                       .and()
                                       .exceptionHandling()
                                       .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                          loginUrlauthenticationEntryPoint(),
                                          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                                       .and());
```

followed by

```
 .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
                            .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository)
                            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler));
```

and

```
 .formLogin(form -> form
                           .loginPage("/index.html")
                           .loginProcessingUrl("/app/internal/login" + "/**").permitAll()
                           .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                           .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
```

And this all worked providing urls for all the login methods. Updating Spring Security 6 (6.1.3) this no longer works. Has this functionality been removed or is there some other way of configuring multiple ways to login with separate url's for handling them all?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems that you met in is deprecated methods and to be sure here are the problem i recommend you to rewrite the `securityFilterChain` something like this:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
          request.requestMatchers("/index.html","/static/**").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

    httpSecurity.exceptionHandling(exceptionH -> {
          exceptionH.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
              loginUrlauthenticationEntryPoint(),
              new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
        });
    httpSecurity.saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2
        .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository)
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler));
    httpSecurity.formLogin(form -> form
        .loginPage("/index.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/app/internal/login/**").permitAll()
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler()));

    return httpSecurity.build();
  }
```

If it also doesn't help you should create two instance of `securityFilter` `@Bean` a good example how to do it you can find here a most upvoted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298001/how-to-use-multiple-login-pages-one-for-admin-and-the-other-one-for-user)

Also you have to check [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)